# MySQL merge two tables in single table with SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, union

I have two tables in MySQL which is following which i want to merge way that it will `table2` host,disabled & disable_reason column and obtain all result from `table1` and create single unified view with JOIN.

I have tired bunch of option like UNION, JOIN etc but i believe i am not close to get that result.

**Table1**

```
 +---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at | id  | internal_id | user_id                          | project_id                       | image_ref                            | kernel_id | ramdisk_id | launch_index | key_name     | key_data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | power_state | vm_state | memory_mb | vcpus | hostname            | host                                  | user_data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | reservation_id | launched_at         | terminated_at | display_name        | display_description | availability_zone | locked | os_type | launched_on                           | instance_type_id | vm_mode | uuid                                 | architecture | root_device_name | access_ip_v4 | access_ip_v6 | config_drive | task_state | default_ephemeral_device | default_swap_device | progress | auto_disk_config | shutdown_terminate | disable_terminate | root_gb | ephemeral_gb | cell_name | node                                  | deleted | locked_by | cleaned | ephemeral_key_uuid |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-09 16:08:52 | 2019-08-09 16:10:45 | NULL       | 873 |        NULL | b6aa784c1e8f448fbbdb17edcbd6c48c | 1d32536d017b42e0a6108cc85764b10f | cb7df5c1-c6eb-40e9-9fc0-78e00bc675f3 |           |            |            0 | jmp1-ssh-key | ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC97GB8C8s4VxGDUj7Cc5v0NhfbycZlOVtCOIXqbZ4oJCtdDYESc+ZbHCyjiEmJRVqdPNN1wRDIkEEaw38tFgRVAbxVfxD6iQSC5i76lq0AseCzFoqTAcmx1PhIFTvL58S9yuoU4CwrB2Nh4sSPycG+ibM6ttLU1vyOIERTNP7QVAscXdC5gw44TXU5PFPlUSO+wOaBZFRP63+57uDPXVJSYFB8aeCxEdGH1XTYXi1+WcIVFCEBTV6GOFhfjUrUauq2bCEybBN+F7SSxPErDeFiozuHCErMVOIteflTXTUVa2o1I6TRN9KFCBSqc/ht3wYMahAcRkC10PRYrrtyQTY/ root@jmp-xx-010101-1.foooo.net |           1 | active   |      8192 |     4 | www01-ssss-010101-1 | ostack-compute-bld-gen-2-52.foooo.net | 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 | r-rrtwqbl5     | 2019-08-09 16:10:45 | NULL          | www01-ssss-010101-1 | NULL                | general           |      0 | NULL    | ostack-compute-bld-gen-2-52.foooo.net |               36 | NULL    | bd3e335f-e0c7-4ee6-bde1-bb07e88b9ef8 | NULL         | /dev/sda         | NULL         | NULL         |              | NULL       | NULL                     | /dev/sdb            |        0 |                1 |                  0 |                 0 |      80 |            0 | NULL      | ostack-compute-bld-gen-2-52.foooo.net |       0 | NULL      |       0 | NULL               |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

**Table2**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at | id  | host                                  | binary       | topic   | report_count | disabled | deleted | disabled_reason | last_seen_up        | forced_down | version | uuid                                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 2019-08-07 02:23:06 | 2019-08-23 19:09:59 | NULL       | 591 | ostack-compute-bld-gen-2-52.foooo.net | nova-compute | compute |       144265 |        0 |       0 | NULL            | 2019-08-23 19:09:59 |           0 |      37 | 2f8e8f59-0e96-434c-a671-6170dffb1043 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: why jQuery tag?

Comment: update your question and show the expected  result

Comment: You may try SELECT columnnamelist FROM table1,table2
                      WHERE table1.col2 = table2.col2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to join this, you'll need to have some kind of common identifier betwen the two tables.  In your example, there's a field named `id`, but the rows don't seem to share the same `id` -- I'll assume for the purposes of this question that this is a truncated set and the fact the `id`s don't match is an oversight.

```
select * from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id
```

You could do this same thing on other matching fields, such as `node` if that's a better shared key:

```
select * from table1, table2 where table1.node = table2.node
```

Either way, you'll have to look at the data and decide how to match the rows to affect the join.

Comment: You got that right... damn it i was so close and finally thought ask expert.. :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, your key is column "host", right? And you want all columns from Table1 and only disable and disable_reason from table2?

Try this:

SELECT t1.*, t2.disabled, t2.disable_reason FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.host = t2.host;